# Python GTK GUI struck

Tags: python, python-2.7, gtk, pygtk

I'm using python gtk to upload file to S3 service by boto API , GUI struck when uploading  a file and releases the GUI after completed process of upload, I'm using thread to show progress of upload in GUI but it struck. Can you some suggestion how to show progress of upload in GUI or any spinner until upload finish. I'm new to python can u suggest how to use thread for GUI also.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk
import boto
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
from boto.s3.key import Key
from boto.exception import S3ResponseError, S3CreateError
import threading
import random, time
gtk.threads_init()

class FractionSetter(threading.Thread):
    """This class sets the fraction of the progressbar"""

    #Thread event, stops the thread if it is set.
    stopthread = threading.Event()

    def run(self):
        """Run method, this is the code that runs while thread is alive."""

        #Importing the progressbar widget from the global scope
        global progressbar 

        #While the stopthread event isn't setted, the thread keeps going on
        while not self.stopthread.isSet() :
            # Acquiring the gtk global mutex
            gtk.threads_enter()
            #Setting a random value for the fraction
            progressbar.set_fraction(random.random())
            # Releasing the gtk global mutex
            gtk.threads_leave()

            #Delaying 100ms until the next iteration
            time.sleep(0.1)

    def stop(self):
        """Stop method, sets the event to terminate the thread's main loop"""
        self.stopthread.set()




class SampleGUI:

    def destroy(self,widget,data=None):
        global fs
    fs.stop()
        gtk.main_quit()

    def get_relative_filename(self, filename):
        f_parts = filename.split('/')
        return f_parts[len(f_parts) - 1]
    def browse(self,widget):
        chooser1 = gtk.FileChooserDialog(title=None,action=gtk.FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_OPEN,
                                  buttons=(gtk.STOCK_CANCEL,gtk.RESPONSE_CANCEL,gtk.STOCK_OPEN,gtk.RESPONSE_OK))
        chooser1.set_show_hidden(True)
        response1 = chooser1.run()
        if response1 == gtk.RESPONSE_OK:
            global filename1
            filename1 = chooser1.get_filename()
            self.textbox.set_text(filename1)
            print filename1
        elif response1 == gtk.RESPONSE_CANCEL:
            chooser1.destroy()

        chooser1.destroy()
    def ensure_bucket(self,connection, bucket, canned_acl=None):
        bucket_instance = None


        try:
            print 'Checking bucket:', bucket
            bucket_instance = connection.get_bucket(bucket)
        except S3ResponseError, s3error:
            s3error_string = '%s' % s3error
            if s3error_string.find('404') >= 0:
                try:
                    bucket_instance = self.create_bucket(connection, bucket,
                            canned_acl)
                except S3CreateError:
                    print 'Unable to create bucket %s' % bucket
                    message1 = gtk.MessageDialog(type=gtk.MESSAGE_INFO, buttons=gtk.BUTTONS_OK)
                    msgg = "Unable to create bucket "+bucket
                    message1.set_markup(msgg)
                    message1.run()
                    message1.destroy() 
            elif s3error_string.find('403') >= 0:
                message1 = gtk.MessageDialog(type=gtk.MESSAGE_ERROR, buttons=gtk.BUTTONS_OK)
                msgg = "You do not have permission to access bucket"
                message1.set_markup(msgg)
                message1.run()
                message1.destroy() 
                d.hide()
                d.destroy()
                print 'You do not have permission to access bucket:', bucket

            else:
                print s3error_string
                sys.exit()
        return bucket_instance

    def upload_file(self,bucket_instance, filename,
                        canned_acl=None):
        fs = FractionSetter()
        global fs
        fs.start()

        print 'Uploading file'
        print "file name",filename
        k = Key(bucket_instance)
        k.key = self.get_relative_filename(filename)
        m_file = open(filename, 'rb')
        print filename
        try:
            k.set_contents_from_file(m_file,policy=canned_acl)
            fs.stop()
        except S3ResponseError, s3error:
            s3error_string = '%s' % s3error
            if s3error_string.find('403') >= 0:
                print 'Permission denied while writing:', k.key
            else:
                print s3error_string
            sys.exit()

    def submitt(self,widget):
        print "submitt"
        global filename1
        print "file name",filename1
        conn = boto.s3.connection.S3Connection(
                   aws_access_key_id='WKy3rMzOWPouVOxK1p3Ar1C2uRBwa2FBXnCw',
                   aws_secret_access_key='UmMJCdlCXvW9DJOgN2MkTOmEXJJKcQu62bFWg',
                   is_secure=False,
                   host="10.184.39.113",
                   port=8773,
                   calling_format=boto.s3.connection.OrdinaryCallingFormat(),
                   path='/services/Walrus',
                   )
        print conn
        bucket_instance = self.ensure_bucket(conn, "sample", canned_acl=None)
        print bucket_instance
        self.upload_file(bucket_instance, filename1, canned_acl=None)
    def pageChanged(self,notebook,page,page_num):
        print "ClickedMe called for"


    def __init__(self):

        self.window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
        self.window.set_position(gtk.WIN_POS_CENTER_ALWAYS)
        self.window.set_size_request(600,400)
        self.window.set_title("UPLOAD A OBJECT TO S3")
        self.window.set_resizable(False)

        self.button1 = gtk.Button("Browse")
        self.button1.connect("clicked",self.browse)

        self.button2 = gtk.Button("Submit")
        self.button2.connect("clicked",self.submitt)

        self.textbox = gtk.Entry()

        self.label1 = gtk.Label("<b>Upload objects to S3</b>")
    self.label1.set_use_markup(True)
        self.table = gtk.Table(5, 5, True)


        notebook = gtk.Notebook()
        notebook.set_tab_pos(gtk.POS_TOP)
        notebook.connect("switch-page",self.pageChanged)
        page1 = gtk.Frame(label=None)

        self.table.attach(self.label1, 1, 4, 1, 2)
        self.table.attach(self.textbox, 1, 4, 2, 3)
        self.table.attach(self.button1, 4, 5, 2, 3, xpadding=20, ypadding=20)

        self.table.attach(self.button2, 4, 5, 3, 4,xpadding=20, ypadding=20)        
        global progressbar
        progressbar = gtk.ProgressBar()
        self.table.attach(progressbar, 0, 5, 4, 5, xpadding=20, ypadding=20)
        page1.add(self.table)

        notebook.append_page(page1,gtk.Label('Upload Files'))
        self.window.add(notebook)
        self.window.show_all()
        self.window.connect("destroy",self.destroy)


    def main(self):
        gtk.main()
        fs = FractionSetter()
        global fs
        fs.start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    base = SampleGUI()
    base.main()
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help

Follow the Pygtk FAQ http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?req=show&file=faq23.020.htp

You might have to add following two lines in your code to continue the main iteration

```
while gtk.events_pending():
    gtk.main_iteration()
```